# Can I adjust connection weights inside a custom layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to update weights in my ANN without using built in optimizers or losses (I have reasons for this and can explain if it's necessary). Because model.compile requires a loss function and an optimizer I define custom dummy loss and optimizer functions and use those. I think these shouldn't have any effect on the weights (tell me if I'm wrong about this).

The way I see it, it seems plausible to update the weights from within my custom layer methods, but the weights are not updating at all.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Layer

class MyLayer(Layer):

    def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
        super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):
        self.kernel = self.kernel * 0
        return K.dot(x, self.kernel)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)

model = Sequential()
model.add(MyLayer(input_shape = (1, 1), output_dim = 1))
model.summary()  


def dummy_loss(y_true, y_pred): return y_pred             

class dummy_opt(keras.optimizers.Optimizer): 
    def __init__(self): return(None)
    def get_updates(self, loss, params): return(np.array(0))
    def get_configs(self): return(0)
dummyOpt = dummy_opt()

model.compile(optimizer = dummyOpt, loss = dummy_loss)

print_weights = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=lambda epoch, logs: print(model.layers[0].get_weights()))
model.fit(x = np.ones(10).reshape(10,1,1), y=np.zeros(10), epochs = 5, verbose = 2, callbacks = [print_weights])
```

I expected the weights to be zero because I multiplied self.kernel by zero in the call method of my custom layer.

Instead, this is the result (the weights do not change)

```
Epoch 1/5  
 4s - loss: 0.0000e+00
[array([[-0.03051628]], dtype=float32)]
Epoch 2/5
 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00
[array([[-0.03051628]], dtype=float32)]
Epoch 3/5
 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00
[array([[-0.03051628]], dtype=float32)]
Epoch 4/5
 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00
[array([[-0.03051628]], dtype=float32)]
Epoch 5/5
 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00
[array([[-0.03051628]], dtype=float32)]
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x1cb0319a908>
```

So why am I not able to change the weights from inside the call method in my custom layer?

Comment: You should use things like `K.set_value`, `K.update`, etc. on your vars.

Comment: Are you sure you need "weights" if you're not going to train them?

Comment: @DanielMöller using K.update(self.kernel, (self.kernel*0)) resulted in the same thing as using self.kernel = self.kernel*0. Also Im planning on updating the weights inside the call method using an unsupervised updating algorithm related to Hebb's Rule. Is the call method not the right place to do this? (i.e. is it possible to update weights from the call method instead of using an optimizer?)